# Como modificar valores do objeto dentro de array no arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso de um help, eu consigo atualizar dados das propriedades do objeto JSON pelo id utilizando o `fetch()`, dessa forma:

```
async updatePericia(){
        const dataJson = JSON.stringify({nome: "Marcos"})
        const req = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/personagem/${id}`,{
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: dataJson
        });

   }
```

Dentro do arquivo db.json possui o objeto na qual quero alterar:

```
{
  "personagem" : 
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "nome" : "Matheus",
    "jogador": "Dominik",
    "idade": 15,
    "sexo": "M",
    "pericias":[
          {"id" : 1, "tipo": "Atletismo", "resultado": 15 },
          {"id" : 2, "tipo": "Atualidades", "resultado": 11 },
          {"id" : 3, "tipo": "Ciência", "resultado": 6 }
    ]
  }
}
```

Como eu faço para modificar os dados dentro do array de objetos "pericias", como por exemplo o "resultado" de "Ciências? de 6 para outro valor?

Comment: Olha, não achei, no teu código nada que referencie `pericias`, e nem o que isso significa... Tu poderias reformular a pergunta, deixando ela mais clara?

Comment: Estou utilizando uma API json server como bancos de dados, o problema é que não sei alterar os valores das propriedades dos objetos dentro de "pericias", que  é o array de objetos dentro de um outro objeto chamado "personagem" no arquivo db.json.

Answer (score -2):

Por favor especifique mais o seu problema, deseja alterar como. Se for como eu entendi você pode acessar o objeto desejado dentro do array "pericias" como um índice. Exemplo:

```
objeto.personagem.pericias[0]
```

E para alterar o valor, basta acessar a propriedade atribuindo o valor. O código final ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<script>
    let jogador = {
        "personagem" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "nome" : "Matheus",
            "jogador": "Dominik",
            "idade": 15,
            "sexo": "M",
            "pericias":[
                {"id" : 1, "tipo": "Atletismo", "resultado": 15 },
                {"id" : 2, "tipo": "Atualidades", "resultado": 11 },
                {"id" : 3, "tipo": "Ciência", "resultado": 6 }
            ]
        }
    };

    // atribuir novo valor
    jogador.personagem.pericias[2].resultado = 5

    console.log(jogador.personagem.pericias[2]);
    // resultado 5
</script>
```

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o Vue.js e uma API JSON Server como banco de dados, meu problema é que não sei modificar os dados um atributo do objeto no array como descrito!